# how to launch an instance of a vm in google compute engine from within a java program

Tags: google-compute-engine

Is there a way to launch a vm of the google compute engine from within a java program?  As an example, consider  a program that is running a process, processing files in one form or another.  Lets call that the master.  Ideally, if the queue size of the files to process exceed a threshold, the java program will launch another instance of a vm that will start executing the process, in a slave configuration.  Once the queue size falls below a certain size, the master will shut down the slave (to save money) and will keep processing the files until such time as the queue gets large enough.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Practically every aspect of GCE can be controlled via API, including VM creating and deletion. You can find java GCE libraries at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries, a complete GCE API reference under https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/parameters

One more thing you may be interested in are Instance Groups. Together with Instance Groups Manager, these two API (and associated java libraries) would allow you to dynamically allocate the processing power your app requires at any one time, all based on a master VM template with automatic replication. Further reading here https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/